# PWM -electronic solenoid valve

Tags: electrical-engineering

I want to control the flow of chemical proportionate to the forward speed of the vehicle( if the speed is more discharge is more vice-versa). Need to integrate vehicle speed with encoder and control the solenoid valve.
Is it possible to change duty cycle of PWM with respect to vehicle forward speed?

Comment: Measure the speed and scale this to 0 to 255 or whatever the maximum value in the PWM control register is. Set the PWM output to that value. Where is the problem? Are you sure that your unnamed solenoid valve has a linear response to PWM control? (It's unlikely.)

Comment: Can you share the specification of your solenoid valve? Is the valve mono stable or bi stable? Additionally I am not too sure how you could PWM on Solenoid.

Comment: Short answer: yes that is possible.  However stack exchange is not a free design service. You should try to figure out how to do this yourself, and then post again with more specific questions. Just to give you somewhere to start: I would recommend using an arduino to do the conversion. Then you will need a speed sensor, and a PWM output circuit (probably a mosfet).